# PyS60 on device debug?

Tags: symbian, pys60

A simple matter makes me suffering as I'm new to PyS60 development.

What is the IDE for

- Executing program on-device with a <strike>single</strike> reasonable amount of clicks,
- Typical step-into, step-over, run-to, watch (used from PC) for the on-device running program ?

Comment: There are some PyS60 debugging techniques described at http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Python_debugging_techniques but not the kind of on-device debugging you seem to be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Real on-device debugging is not (yet) possible, I'm afraid. You have to use popup notes, audio.say() or write to log files.

Personally I forward sys.stdout and sys.edterr into a log file and use sys.settrace() and 
sys.setprofile(). Works reasonably well, no need to modify real app source code, just dump EVERYTHING into a log file and do search afterwards.